# If jsp generated class extends HttpServlet, how come we can extend it with one more class using extend tag?

Tags: java, jsp, multiple-inheritance

As we know jsp get compiled to a class which extends httpservlet then how it can again extend Class1.

Comment: We are here to help you solve your issues. Rather then completely answering and writing code for you. Please let us us know what efforts have you put to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in `java` to extend two `class` at the same time .

`java` doesn't support multiple inheritance in context of class but for `Interface` it is there.

So, You can implement multiple `Interfaces` in a single class but multiple class cannot be extended.

but you can implement this using multi-level Inheritance in `Java`. As such example abbriviates

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

class A extends HttpServlet{
// your Body and implement Method that you need
}
```

and now You can extend that class A into your own business logic Class B.
As shown below...

```
import package.name.A;

Class B extends A{
// Now HttpServlet is your parent class too in heirarchy..
}
```

Thanks